# React JS: Obtaining two Nav Links for single Nav Link

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code for nav bar:

```
<Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto"></Nav>
    <Nav>
        <Nav.Link href="/Home">HOME</Nav.Link>
        {this.state.role== 'admin' && <Nav.Link href={"/adminhome/"+this.state.uid}>DASHBOARD</Nav.Link>}
        {this.state.role== 'farmer' && <Nav.Link href={"/userhome/"+this.state.uid}>DASHBOARD</Nav.Link>}
        {this.state.role== 'buyer' && <Nav.Link href={"/buyerhome/"+this.state.uid}>DASHBOARD</Nav.Link>}              
        {this.state.role== 'buyer' && <Nav.Link href={"/buyerhome/"+this.state.uid}>DASHBOARD</Nav.Link>}
        <NavDropdown title={window.localStorage.getItem("username")} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href={"/updateProfile/" + this.state.uid}>Update Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/Home" onClick={() => window.sessionStorage.clear() }>Sign out</NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
</Navbar.Collapse>
```

When this component is rendered, I get two nav links in place of one.

[This is rendered on browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOJY3.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It appears twice because you wrote the same code twice. Please delete one of

```
{this.state.role== 'buyer' && <Nav.Link href={"/buyerhome/"+this.state.uid}>DASHBOARD</Nav.Link>}
```

Comment: Wow, it can't be that obvious... I am using VS code and I just checked back, there is only one of those lines. But when I paste it here, it becomes two.